# Ruby Gems possible download source IP addresses

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I've been trying to help a developer in my company who was having trouble installing gems via the command `gem install` for example `gem install cucumber`. The problem seems to be proxy related in that the ruby program/command prompt (I don't pretend do know what it is) cannot get out through the proxy. We set the variables for a proxy bypass we have but it simply doesn't work.

We have a direct internet connection available for testing and when the PC was connected to that, the gem install completed just fine, confirming our firewall suspicions.

Our security team won't simply allow a program or PC to access whatever it wants on the Internet, and for other programs an exclusion is made for the IP address the program wants to connect to. I'm of the understanding that ruby gems may connect to a number of different IP addresses in order to download and install gems.

Does anyone know, or is it possible for me to find out all the possible IP addresses that installing gems may require?

If any of this sounds like a bad request, it's just my lack of understanding around ruby gems, installing gems etc. Hopefully you get the idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: On Linux, you can use `strace -e connect gem install <gemname>` (on a system where you are not firewalled) to see all connections it is making.

Comment: Sorry, as the use of Ruby is not something I'm familiar with I didn't even think to put the OS. It's Windows 7. Thanks.